# Async friendly DispatcherTimer wrapper/subclass

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, .net-4.5, dispatchertimer

I have a `DispatcherTimer` running in my code that fire every 30 seconds to update system status from the server. The timer fires in the client even if I'm debugging my server code so if I've been debugging for 5 minutes I may end up with a dozen timeouts in the client. Finally decided I needed to fix this so looking to make a more `async` / `await` friendly DispatcherTimer.

- Code running in `DispatcherTimer` must be configurable whether it is reentrant or not (i.e. if the task is already running it should not try to run it again)
- Should be task based (whether or not this requires I actually expose Task at the root is a gray area)
- Should be able to run async code and `await` on tasks to complete
- Whether it wraps or extends DispatcherTimer probably doesn't really matter but wrapping it may be slightly less ambiguous if you don't know how to use it
- Possibly expose bindable properties for `IsRunning` for UI

Comment: Have you looked at `Task.Delay()`?

Comment: @svick not quite sure what you meant unless you're talking about an infinite loop of some sort but then where would that run

Comment: Yeah, I did mean something like an infinite loop. If you `await` it from the UI thread, then it will resume there too. And you can call it from an `async void` method, which means it will run independently of the code that called it.

Answer (score 12):

Here's what I came up with.

- `SmartDispatcherTimer` Extends `DispatcherTimer` (was easiest way to get this up and running)
- Has a `TickTask` property to provide a `Task` to handle the logic
- Has an `IsReentrant` property (of course the whole point is that I want it to not be reentrant so normally this is false)
- It assumes anything you're calling is fully awaitable - or you'd end up losing the reentrancy protection benefits

Usage:

```
        var timer = new SmartDispatcherTimer();
        timer.IsReentrant = false;
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        timer.TickTask = async () =>
        {
            StatusMessage = "Updating...";  // MVVM property
            await UpdateSystemStatus(false);
            StatusMessage = "Updated at " + DateTime.Now;
        };
        timer.Start();
```

Here's the code. Would love to hear any thoughts on it

```
public class SmartDispatcherTimer : DispatcherTimer
{
    public SmartDispatcherTimer()
    {
        base.Tick += SmartDispatcherTimer_Tick;
    }

    async void SmartDispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TickTask == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No task set!");
            return;
        }

        if (IsRunning && !IsReentrant)
        {
            // previous task hasn't completed
            Debug.WriteLine("Task already running");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            // we're running it now
            IsRunning = true;

            Debug.WriteLine("Running Task");
            await TickTask.Invoke();
            Debug.WriteLine("Task Completed");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Task Failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            // allow it to run again
            IsRunning = false;
        }
    }

    public bool IsReentrant { get; set; }
    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

    public Func<Task> TickTask { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is quite good solution, I din't find anything better till now. We implemented something similar. But tricky part comes if you want to stop the timer and make sure the task are finished :)

Comment: Why is `SmartDispatcherTimer_Tick` `Void` and not a `Task`?

Comment: @decoder94 because that's just the event handler callback. Definitely welcome better implementations if you see a way to improve this. Wow was this really 5.5 years ago!

Comment: @Simon_Weaver over five years ago but I am brand new to async. I am not saying it is wrong am not sure it is just that I read we should use async task and not void(with the exception of methods for buttons). I am here because I would like to use it and I am using void. I was just asking because I was curious.